# SSLenabled kafka configuration: Error : no suitable method found in creating map/configuration

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to kafka-stream and we are trying to send message to kafka topic protected with SSL. 
Hence, we have added extra SSl-config-properties to the stream configuration as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamConfig {

  @Autowired
  private PreferredMediaMsgStreamProperties appProperties;


  @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.properties.receive.buffer.bytes}")
  private String receiveBufferBytes;

  @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
  public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = Map.of(
            StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appProperties.getApplicationId(),
            StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, appProperties.getBootstrapServers(),

            //configure the following three settings for SSL Encryption
            CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL",
            SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/etc/ssl/container/truststore.jks",
            SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "changeit",

            // configure the following three settings for SSL Authentication
            SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/etc/ssl/container/server.jks",
            SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "changeit",
            SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "changeit",

            StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PreferredMediaMsgStreamProperties.Constants.KEY_SERDE.getClass().getName(),
            StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, PreferredMediaMsgStreamProperties.Constants.VALUE_SERDE.getClass().getName(),
            StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName(),
            StreamsConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, receiveBufferBytes

    );

    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = Map.of(
            AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, appProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
  }

}
```

**And the error message , I am seeing during compilation is:**

```
error: no suitable method found for of(String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String)
    Map<String, Object> props = Map.of(
                                   ^
    method Map.<K#1,V#1>of() is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#1,V#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#2,V#2>of(K#2,V#2) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#2,V#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#3,V#3>of(K#3,V#3,K#3,V#3) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#3,V#3
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#4,V#4>of(K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#4,V#4
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#5,V#5>of(K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#5,V#5
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#6,V#6>of(K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#6,V#6
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#7,V#7>of(K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#7,V#7
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#8,V#8>of(K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#8,V#8
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#9,V#9>of(K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#9,V#9
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#10,V#10>of(K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#10,V#10
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Map.<K#11,V#11>of(K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) K#11,V#11
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where K#1,V#1,K#2,V#2,K#3,V#3,K#4,V#4,K#5,V#5,K#6,V#6,K#7,V#7,K#8,V#8,K#9,V#9,K#10,V#10,K#11,V#11 are type-variables:
    K#1 extends Object declared in method <K#1,V#1>of()
    V#1 extends Object declared in method <K#1,V#1>of()
    K#2 extends Object declared in method <K#2,V#2>of(K#2,V#2)
    V#2 extends Object declared in method <K#2,V#2>of(K#2,V#2)
    K#3 extends Object declared in method <K#3,V#3>of(K#3,V#3,K#3,V#3)
    V#3 extends Object declared in method <K#3,V#3>of(K#3,V#3,K#3,V#3)
    K#4 extends Object declared in method <K#4,V#4>of(K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4)
    V#4 extends Object declared in method <K#4,V#4>of(K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4,K#4,V#4)
    K#5 extends Object declared in method <K#5,V#5>of(K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5)
    V#5 extends Object declared in method <K#5,V#5>of(K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5,K#5,V#5)
    K#6 extends Object declared in method <K#6,V#6>of(K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6)
    V#6 extends Object declared in method <K#6,V#6>of(K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6,K#6,V#6)
    K#7 extends Object declared in method <K#7,V#7>of(K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7)
    V#7 extends Object declared in method <K#7,V#7>of(K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7,K#7,V#7)
    K#8 extends Object declared in method <K#8,V#8>of(K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8)
    V#8 extends Object declared in method <K#8,V#8>of(K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8,K#8,V#8)
    K#9 extends Object declared in method <K#9,V#9>of(K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9)
    V#9 extends Object declared in method <K#9,V#9>of(K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9,K#9,V#9)
    K#10 extends Object declared in method <K#10,V#10>of(K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10)
    V#10 extends Object declared in method <K#10,V#10>of(K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10,K#10,V#10)
    K#11 extends Object declared in method <K#11,V#11>of(K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11)
    V#11 extends Object declared in method <K#11,V#11>of(K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11,K#11,V#11)
Note: /Users/pbose/patrali_sand/notification-preference-stream/src/main/java/com/talentreef/notification/preference/utils/RecipientPoolValueJoiner.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

**If I take out the propertiesbelow, then it compiles fine:**

```
//configure the following three settings for SSL Encryption
CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL",
SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/etc/ssl/container/truststore.jks",
SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "changeit",

// configure the following three settings for SSL Authentication
SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/etc/ssl/container/server.jks",
SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "changeit",
SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "changeit",
```

May I get any insight on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map.of()` has overloads for a maximum of 10 entries ( check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) ) . You have 11 in total. That is why, when you remove 6 of them compiles.

If you want this to work use `Map.ofEntries()`. This method takes a variable argument and it doesn't have limitations regarding the number of entries.